# Vue.js components in a Laravel 5.4 project work locally but not on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, npm, vue.js

Issue: 
I have a Laravel 5.4 project with Vue.js and use Heroku for deployment. Everything has been running fine until today when I noticed the changes I made in the Vue component file were working fine locally, but not being reflected on Heroku.

In the past this happened when I forgot to run npm run build, but when I executed npm run build this time I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-42-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/caseydemo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/node" "/home/caseydemo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: build
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/caseydemo/Documents/gotcha/npm-debug.log
```

I wasn’t sure what to make of this so I tried removing my node modules and re-installing them with the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

I got the following error after npm install ran:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. Not really sure what to do next, any help is appreciated.

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "hover.css": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your `package.json` file. It's likely that you haven't defined a `build` script in that file. (I don't think those NPM warnings are relevant. You're just seeing some optional dependencies not get installed since they're only for macOS.)

Comment: I added the package.json file into the question - I assumed that npm install would create the build script for me as I am pretty new to Laravel. Do I need to create the script myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a method `build` defined in your scripts, you're looking for `prod` or `production`:

```
npm run production
```

The error message you received tells you as much:

```
npm ERR! missing script: build
```

And if you look in the `scripts` definition in `package.json`, you'll see there is no `build` defined for sure.

Comment: I ran `npm run production` and it said it finished successfully - however my `package.json` file still doesn't have a build method for some reason. Do I need to create one myself?

Comment: Why do you need a build method?

Comment: @CaseyDeMattina You don't need a `build` method, that sounds like something from a previous version of `laravel elixir` perhaps. This is the correct approach.

Comment: also after running `npm run production` and pushing to heroku I do not see any changes that I have made for the past day or so.

Comment: @CaseyDeMattina Seems like a separate issue. Could be that you're not running this in `postinstall` in Heroku. Given that this issue is solved, please accept the answer and formulate a new question where we can attempt to solve that problem.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't know what postinstall is, I'll look it up

Comment: Im having a similar error and have been stucked on this. can anyone help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084954/laravel-vuejs-app-does-not-update-after-deploying-to-heroku